# Mock a singleton method call from constructor

Tags: android, mocking, mockito, android-testing

I want to mock the singleton class method, which was called from the constructor.

```
class client {
   client(String s1, Strings s2, Context ctx) {
      getInstance().init(ctx);
   }

   ConfigurationManage getInstance() {
      return ConfigurationManager.getInstance();
   }
}
```

How can i mock the getInstance() when this function was called from constructor.

How do mock this function in my test class?

My test class is below:

```
 class clientTest() {
    @Test
    Public void test(){
      ConfigurationManager instance = mock(ConfigurationManager.class)
      Client client = new Client("str1", "str2", mock(Context.class))
    }
  }
```

How could i mock the getInstance() while calling this from constructor.

Could anyone please help me out on this.